# How to connect a database to crystal report at run time?

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I am developing winform application in vb6. I am using crystal report 4.6. I have created a crystal report which shows all data from a table (MS Access).  And I unchecked save data with report and i saved the report. I just want to invoke it in application. So I included the component CrystalReportControl in my application. Now i want to set the records to be displayed in the report. The records are selected according to the user input to the text box.
Records are retrived from the database is done in following code.

```
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Private Sub Command1_Click()
      Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
      conn.Open "provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path &"\faculty.mdb"
      Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
      rs.Open "select * from facultydetails where eid=1234", conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic
      CrystalReport1.ReportFileName = App.Path & "\faculty.rpt"
      Set CrystalReport1.DataSource = rs
      CrystalReport1.Action = 1
    End Sub
```

Gives an error for the line: Set CrystalReport1.DataSource = rs :
as Property is write-only.
Tell me how the records of the report can be dynamic? Plz help me...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Set CrystalReport1.DataSource = rs
```

do

```
CrystalReport1.DataSource = rs
```

EDIT:

Take a look at the following example and see if that will help you:

```
'CrystalReport1 is the name of the dsr file
Dim Report As New CrystalReport1    

Dim cdoRowset As CrystalDataObject.CrystalComObject
Dim varArray() As Variant

'Open ADO Connection
Set m_cnAdo = New ADODB.Connection
m_cnAdo.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};UID=[UserID];PWD=[Password]" _
            & ";SERVER=[Server];DATABASE=[Database]"

m_cnAdo.Open

Dim rsAdo As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmdAdo As ADODB.Command


'Using Embedded Query
Set cmdAdo = New ADODB.Command
Set rsAdo = New ADODB.Recordset
cmdAdo.ActiveConnection = m_cnAdo
cmdAdo.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Param = " & lngParam1
cmdAdo.CommandType = adCmdText


Set rsAdo = cmdAdo.Execute    
Report.Database.SetDataSource rsAdo, 3, 1
```

Comment: It Says Type Mismatch for same line.

Comment: it says user defined type not defined for the line 
dim report as new crystalreport1. I should include some references i think.